# crashes don't appear on crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have searched a lot for a solution to my case but no answer. I proceed with the installation for crashlytics on iOS, but the crashes don't appear on crashlytics. There are no missing DSYM, and I set the 'Debug Information Format' to 'DWARF with dSYM File'. I tried a lot of solutions but no one fit my case. Any help is appreciated!

[when I press run I get the following from fabric window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1jhI.png)

[the updated output of the console when I press run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCjeR.png)

Comment: Are you checking in Release mode or Debug mode?

Comment: Assuming that you are pretty sure that you have done the setup of crashlytics integration, are have you checked the bundle ID for the app? also, you might want try to cause a crash (`Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`)...

Comment: Can you enable debug mode https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html, cause a test crash (https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features), and then share the console log output when you relaunch the app?

Comment: @AustinMichael in debug mode, also I tried to launch the app then press the stop button in xcode, then open the app from the device and cause the crash, then relaunch it again to deliver the crash, and nothing appears

Comment: @AhmadF yes I checked the bundle ID, and this is the way I use to cause the crash Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()

Comment: @Alexizamerican I added an image for the output after relaunching the app again after crash

Comment: have you set 'Debug Information Format' to 'DWARF with dSYM File' in debug mode?

Comment: @AustinMichael yes both in debug and release mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the output from your log, it seems like you're using Firebase Crash Reporting and not Firebase Crashlytics. If you want to use Crashlytics, you need to remove the Firebase Crash Reporting SDK (you can't have 2 exception handlers in iOS apps) and then follow the instructions for installing and setting up Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: I removed FirebaseCrash and I get the following two images uploaded up. @Alexizamerican

Comment: okay the problem is done when I remove firebase crash and fix a minor bug